# How to properly merge multiple FlowFile's?

Tags: json, apache-nifi

I use `MergeContent` 1.3.0 in order to merge FlowFiles from 2 sources: 1) from ListenHTTP and 2) from `QueryElasticsearchHTTP`.

The problem is that the merging result is a list of JSON strings. How can I convert them into a single JSON string?

```
{"event-date":"2017-08-08T00:00:00"}{"event-date":"2017-02-23T00:00:00"}{"eid":1,"zid":1,"latitude":38.3,"longitude":2.4}
```

I would to get this result:

```
{"event-date":["2017-08-08T00:00:00","2017-02-23T00:00:00"],"eid":1,"zid":1,"latitude":38.3,"longitude":2.4}
```

Is it possible?

**UPDATE:**

After changing data structure in Elastic, I was able to come up with the following output result of `MergeContent`. Now I have a common field `eid` in both JSON strings. I would like to merge these strings by `eid` in order to get a single JSON file. Which operator should I use?

```
{"eid":"1","zid":1,"latitude":38.3,"longitude":2.4}{"eid":"1","dates":{"event-date":["2017-08-08","2017-02-23"]}}
```

I need to get the following output:

```
{"eid":"1","zid":1,"latitude":38.3,"longitude":2.4,"dates":{"event-date":["2017-08-08","2017-02-23"]}}
```

It was suggested to use `ExecuteScript` to merge files. However I cannot figure out how to do this. This is what I tried:

```
import json
import java.io
from org.apache.commons.io import IOUtils
from java.nio.charset import StandardCharsets
from org.apache.nifi.processor.io import StreamCallback

class ModJSON(StreamCallback):
  def __init__(self):
        pass
  def process(self, inputStream, outputStream):
    text = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
    obj = json.loads(text)
    newObj = {
          "eid": obj['eid'],
          "zid": obj['zid'],
          ...
        }
    outputStream.write(bytearray(json.dumps(newObj, indent=4).encode('utf-8')))

flowFile1 = session.get()
flowFile2 = session.get()
if (flowFile1 != None && flowFile2 != None):
  # WHAT SHOULD I PUT HERE??
  flowFile = session.write(flowFile, ModJSON())
  flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, "filename", flowFile.getAttribute('filename').split('.')[0]+'_translated.json')
session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
session.commit()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The example how to read multiple files from incoming queue using filtering

Assume you have multiple pairs of flow files with following content:

`{"eid":"1","zid":1,"latitude":38.3,"longitude":2.4}`

and

`{"eid":"1","dates":{"event-date":["2017-08-08","2017-02-23"]}}`

The same value of `eid` field provides a link between pairs.

Before merging we have to extract the value of `eid` field and put it into na attribute of the flow file for fast filtering.

Use the `EvaluateJsonPath` processor with properties:

```
Destination :  flowfile-attribute 
eid         :  $.eid
```

After this you'll have new `eid` attribute of the flow file.

Then use ExecuteScript processor with groovy language and with following code:

```
import org.apache.nifi.processor.FlowFileFilter;
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder

//get first flow file
def ff0 = session.get()
if(!ff0)return

def eid = ff0.getAttribute('eid')

//try to find files with same attribute in the incoming queue
def ffList = session.get(new FlowFileFilter(){
    public FlowFileFilterResult filter(FlowFile ff) {
        if( eid == ff.getAttribute('eid') )return FlowFileFilterResult.ACCEPT_AND_CONTINUE
        return FlowFileFilterResult.REJECT_AND_CONTINUE
    }
})

//let's assume you require two additional files in queue with the same attribute

if( !ffList || ffList.size()<1 ){
    //if less than required
    //rollback current session with penalize retrieved files so they will go to the end of the incoming queue
    //with pre-configured penalty delay (default 30sec)
    session.rollback(true)
    return
}

//let's put all in one list to simplify later iterations
ffList.add(ff0)

if( ffList.size()>2 ){
    //for example unexpected situation. you have more files then expected
    //redirect all of them to failure
    session.transfer(ffList, REL_FAILURE)
    return
}

//create empty map (aka json object)
def json = [:]
//iterate through files parse and merge attributes
ffList.each{ff->
    session.read(ff).withStream{rawIn->
        def fjson = new JsonSlurper().parse(rawIn)
        json.putAll(fjson)
    }
}
//create new flow file and write merged json as a content
def ffOut = session.create()
ffOut = session.write(ffOut,{rawOut->
    rawOut.withWriter("UTF-8"){writer->
        new JsonBuilder(json).writeTo(writer)
    }
} as OutputStreamCallback )
//set mime-type
ffOut = session.putAttribute(ffOut, "mime.type", "application/json")

session.remove(ffList)
session.transfer(ffOut, REL_SUCCESS)
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help. But I have no experience in Groovy. Could you please put such example in Python or at least give some example how to merge files using `JsonSlurper`?

Comment: I found this approach for Groovy, but how can I get `json1` and `json2`? `def file1 = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json1)
def file2 = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json2)  

JsonOutput.prettyPrint(JsonOutput.toJson ([file1: file1, file2: file2]))` Should they be `ffList[0]` and `ffList[1]`?

Comment: could you specify what you have in each flowFile?

Comment: In the first FlowFile I have `{"eid":"1","zid":1,"latitude":38.3,"longitude":2.4}` and in the second FlowFile I have `{"eid":"1","dates":{"event-date":["2017-08-08","2017-02-23"]}}`. Regarding incorrect JSON file, this is what I see as an output of `MergeContents`. Therefore I substituted `MergeContents` by `ExecuteScript`. According to your example, instead of `s` I have `ffList` with 2 files mentioned above. The question is how to extract them from the list `ffList` and put into a single FlowFile?

Comment: i've added the json parse/merge code,but did not test it.

Comment: I am testing your solution. One doubt: with this line of code `if( !ffList || ffList.size()<2 ){` you assume that there should be 2 files in one queue or totally 2 files? The thing is that I have 1 file in queue #1 and 1 file in queue #2.

Comment: I have a further question related to this code. Maybe you might answer it easily. Thanks: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46035920/why-merging-is-applied-only-to-the-first-pair-of-files-while-others-get-queued

Comment: make sure all flow files before this script has an attribute `eid` evaluated. you can use EvaluateJSONPath processor for this. add some logging to this code `println "files found with eid=$eid : $ffList "` to see how many files were found with id...

Comment: Yes, all files have `eid`, because I send them manually from terminal and I only change latitude: `curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"eid":1,"zid":1,"latitude":38.3,"longitude":2.4}' http://localhost:8085/contentListener`. Then in Elasticsearch I have only one entry and it has `eid`.

Comment: no, i mean eid attribute of the flow file , not the content. are you using `EvaluateJSONPath` ?

Comment: I don't use `EvaluateJSONPath`. Should I use it before `ExecuteScript`?

Comment: exactly. to extract the `eid` value from the context and put it into fast accessible attributes of the flow file. just create `EvaluateJsonPath` processor with properties: `Destination=flowfile-attribute`, `eid=$.eid`

Comment: Ok, I added `EvaluateJsonPath` before `ExecuteScript`, so that `EvaluateJsonPath` has two inputs, and `ExecuteScript` has one input. In Properties of `EvaluateJsonPath` I defined `Destination=flowfile-attribute` and i created a property `AttributeName` with the value `eid=$.eid`. The same issue - only first pair of files gets saved.

Comment: Attribute name 'eid' and value for it '$.eid' . As result you should have attribute with name 'eid' after this processor.

Answer (score 4):

Joining together two different types of data is not really what MergeContent was made to do.

You would need to write a custom processor, or custom script, that understood your incoming data formats and created the new output.

If you have ListenHttp connected to QueryElasticSearchHttp, meaning that you are triggering the query based on the flow file coming out of ListenHttp, then you may want to make a custom version of QueryElasticSearchHttp that takes the content of the incoming flow file and joins it together with any of the outgoing results.

Here is where the query result is currently written to a flow file:

https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-elasticsearch-bundle/nifi-elasticsearch-processors/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/processors/elasticsearch/QueryElasticsearchHttp.java#L360

Another option is to use ExecuteScript and write a script that could take multiple flow files and merge them together in the way you described.

Comment: I always have 1 FlowFile with `eid`. Then it triggers the creation of a second FlowFile with multiple `event-date`. Therefore, the expected result is structured as it's shown in the question.

Comment: Which operator should I use to write a custom processor? Maybe it's possible to use `ExecuteScript` with multiple FlowFiles? Indeed I use `MergeContent` in order to get an input file for `ExecuteScript`. I thought that it would simplify processing.

Comment: I see, so you have ListenHttp connected to QueryElasticSearchHTTP, so that the query is triggered by incoming flow file?

Comment: Yes, right. Please see my update (in a couple of minutes), because I was able to slightly advance the solution. I guess that now I lack some basic step.

Comment: Please check my update. I think that now the problem is solvable using built-in operators of Nifi. But I am a newbie. So, your help will be appreciated.

Comment: I read your updated answer. I would opt for `ExecuteScript`, however I don't understand how to get both files inside the script (e.g. Python). I can access a file using `flowFile = session.get()`. But in case of 2 files, what should I do?

Comment: You can make multiple calls to session.get()

Comment: Could you give an example of how to read multiple FlowFiles? (see my update, where I started to do this).