# How to substitute particular field of FlowFile by the field from another FlowFile?

Tags: apache-nifi

I have the output FlowFile #1 of `ExecuteScript` and the output FlowFile #2 of another `ExecuteScript`.

**FlowFile #1**

```
{
 "field1": "val",
 "field2": "val"
}
```

**FlowFile #2**

```
{
  "field2": "abc"
}
```

Which processor should I use in order to substitute the value `val` of `field1` in FlowFile #1 by the value `abc` of `field2` from FlowFile #2?

I don't want to use MergeContent, because what I need is just to replace the value.

**UPDATE:**

In `UpdateAttribute` I set the property `filename` equal to `${UUID()}`. Then in `ExecuteScript` named as `Merge inputs into single FlowFile` I use the code shown below. The files are not merged and are queued.

The output of `Replacetext` is like FlowFile #2, and the output of `UpdateAttribute` is like FlowFile #1.

[image]

```
import org.apache.nifi.processor.FlowFileFilter;
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder

//get first flow file
def ff0 = session.get()
if(!ff0)return

def filename = ff0.getAttribute('filename')

//try to find files with same attribute in the incoming queue
def ffList = session.get(new FlowFileFilter(){
    public FlowFileFilterResult filter(FlowFile ff) {
        if( filename == ff.getAttribute('filename') )return FlowFileFilterResult.ACCEPT_AND_CONTINUE
        return FlowFileFilterResult.REJECT_AND_CONTINUE
    }
})

//let's assume you require two additional files in queue with the same attribute

if( !ffList || ffList.size()<1 ){
    session.rollback(true)
    return
}

//let's put all in one list to simplify later iterations
ffList.add(ff0)

if( ffList.size()>2 ){
    session.transfer(ffList, REL_FAILURE)
    return
}

//create empty map (aka json object)
def json = [:]
//iterate through files parse and merge attributes
ffList.each{ff->
    session.read(ff).withStream{rawIn->
        def fjson = new JsonSlurper().parse(rawIn)
        json.putAll(fjson)
    }
}
//create new flow file and write merged json as a content
def ffOut = session.create()
ffOut = session.write(ffOut,{rawOut->
    rawOut.withWriter("UTF-8"){writer->
        new JsonBuilder(json).writeTo(writer)
    }
} as OutputStreamCallback )
//set mime-type
ffOut = session.putAttribute(ffOut, "mime.type", "application/json")

session.remove(ffList)
session.transfer(ffOut, REL_SUCCESS)
```

**UDPATE #2:**

[image]

Comment: your question is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45982908/how-to-properly-merge-multiple-flowfiles/45996362#45996362). or just create one `ExecuteScript` instead of two )

Comment: @daggett: In my previous question I wanted to merge two FlowFile's by the value of particular field that was common in both files. Here I do not have a common value, because `field2` has different values. I don't understand how can I make this substitution using `ExecuteScript` that has two input FlowFiles. Could you show please such example (if possible, in Python)?

Comment: @daggett: If I create a single `ExecuteScript`, then anyway it will have two input FlowFiles (that's because of the logic of my example). I don't know how to handle the replacement.

Comment: link to example in first comment. if there are hundred files in your input queue how could you choose two correct 2 files from this list?

Comment: @daggett: That's the case. I take an original FlowFile generated by `ListeHTTP`. Then I enrich these data by getting additional data using `InvokeHTTP` and now I want just to add these additional data (FlowFile #2) to the original FlowFile #1, but they do not have a common field.

Comment: So generate such id attribute with `UpdateAttribute` and [UUID function](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#uuid) just after you received message from ListenHTTP. And use it for merging content of two flow files.

Comment: @daggett: Ok, I think that I get the point. Could you please show how to generate an attribute with `UpdateAttribute` and UUID? Thanks.

Comment: @daggett: I just created a new property `filename` with the value `${uuid}`. But what I don't understand is that now only FlowFile #1 has this attribute, while the output of `InvokeHTTP` does not have the same value of `filename`.

Comment: `InvokeHTTP` should not update `filename` attribute.  1) could you update your question and add a screenshot of your flow? 2) Are you sure you have filename attribute with `${UUID()}` value before InvokeHTTP?

Comment: @daggett: Please see my update. This is what I have now. There is no error message, but FlowFile's are not merged.

Comment: just change the link. instead of `Get events -> Create the body` create `UpdateAttribute -> Create the body`. So `UpdateAttribute` will precede  both: `Create the body` and `Merge`

Comment: @daggett: Now it works, but only when I execute the first curl POST query for `ListenHTTP`. The remaining FlowFile's get queued and are not merged. Why? Please see my new update with the screenshot.

Comment: @daggett: I checked queues. the values of `filename` are the same in both queues. So, FlowFiles can be merged, but they are not. Maybe there is some problem with the script, but it's just a copy-paste from your first link.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153881/discussion-between-daggett-and-dinosaurius).

Answer (score 0):

The full details can be found in the chat thanks to @dagget, but to ensure this question does not seem unanswered I will post the key points here.

1. Ensure that an id is added to the flow before it diverges, this allows you to bring the relevant message pairs together again.
2. Disable the rollback(penalty) to avoid waiting too long for both halves of a message to become available again